# Mongo DB I try to add new field

Tags: mongodb

I try to add new field in collection, for all documents. SOmeone knows what's going on? Why I get this error? I try to invoke this command from Intellij, I'm connected to remote mongodb

```
db.commands.update({},
             {$set : {"response":""}},
             {upsert:false,
               multi:true})
```

> [2020-07-10 10:50:21] java.lang.Exception: TypeError: invokeMember
> (updateMany) on
> JavaObject[com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider@6b25905f
> (com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider)] failed due to:
> Arity error - expected: 6 actual: 5 [2020-07-10 10:50:21] TypeError:
> invokeMember (updateMany) on
> JavaObject[com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider@6b25905f
> (com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider)] failed due to:
> Arity error - expected: 6 actual: 5 [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at
> Collection. (all-standalone.js:76347:63) [2020-07-10
> 10:50:21] at step (all-standalone.js:75906:23) [2020-07-10 10:50:21]
> at Object. (all-standalone.js:75887:53) [2020-07-10
> 10:50:21] at all-standalone.js:75881:71 [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at
> Promise.Promise (native) [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at __awaiter
> (all-standalone.js:75877:12) [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at
> Collection.update (all-standalone.js:76339:16) [2020-07-10 10:50:21]
> at user_script:1:42 [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at user_script:1:1
> [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at ShellEvaluator.
> (all-standalone.js:86562:36) [2020-07-10 10:50:21] TypeError:
> invokeMember (updateMany) on
> JavaObject[com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider@6b25905f
> (com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider)] failed due to:
> Arity error - expected: 6 actual: 5 [2020-07-10 10:50:21] TypeError:
> invokeMember (updateMany) on
> JavaObject[com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider@6b25905f
> (com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider)] failed due to:
> Arity error - expected: 6 actual: 5 [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at
> Collection. (all-standalone.js:76347:63) [2020-07-10
> 10:50:21] at step (all-standalone.js:75906:23) [2020-07-10 10:50:21]
> at Object. (all-standalone.js:75887:53) [2020-07-10
> 10:50:21] at all-standalone.js:75881:71 [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at
> Promise.Promise (native) [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at __awaiter
> (all-standalone.js:75877:12) [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at
> Collection.update (all-standalone.js:76339:16) [2020-07-10 10:50:21]
> at user_script:1:42 [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at user_script:1:1
> [2020-07-10 10:50:21] at ShellEvaluator.
> (all-standalone.js:86562:36) orbital> db.commands.update({},
> {$set : {"response":""}},
> {upsert:false,
> multi:true})`enter code here`

Comment: Or maybe I don't need to add new field by script because in Spring Boot it's added automatically? I just added new field to the entity

Comment: Try [`updateMany()` method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)